# What is the purpose of coroutine yield()?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I'm not exactly sure what is the purpose of the `yield` function. Can you check this example I have?

I am following an example [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions).

Here is the code:

```
val job = launch {
    val child = launch {
        try {
            delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        } finally {
            println("Child is cancelled")
        }
    }
    yield() //why do i need this ???????
    println("Cancelling child")
    child.cancel()
    child.join()
    yield()
    println("Parent is not cancelled")
}
job.join()
```

When I comment out the first yield I get the following results:

- Cancelling child

  Parent is not cancelled

but if I leave the yield as it is I get:

- Cancelling child

  Child is cancelled

  Parent is not cancelled

What does it mean to use `yield` here?

Comment: I'm not a kotliner myself now. In my opinion even more interesting: "do we need `child.join()`?". Look at [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Skfmf8tL4) - I slightly modified this example and played with commenting-uncommenting `yields` and `joins` in several places. Looks like `join` yields a thread too.

Comment: yield() basically means that the thread is not doing anything that important and if other threads  need to be run, they should run. so yah i guess join would do that. i'll look into it. thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html

> Yields a thread (or thread pool) of the current coroutine dispatcher
>   to other coroutines to run. If the coroutine dispatcher does not have
>   its own thread pool (like Dispatchers.Unconfined) then this function
>   does nothing, but checks if the coroutine Job was completed. This
>   suspending function is cancellable. If the Job of the current
>   coroutine is cancelled or completed when this suspending function is
>   invoked or while this function is waiting for dispatching, it resumes
>   with CancellationException.

It accomplishes at least a few things

1. It temporarily deprioritises the current long running CPU task, giving other tasks a fair opportunity to run.
2. Checks whether the current job is cancelled, since otherwise in a tight CPU bound loop, the job may not check until the end.
3. Allows for progress of child jobs, where there is contention because more jobs than threads. This may be important where the current job should adapt based on progress of other jobs.

Answer (score 30):

After some research, I see that the term `yield` is actually from computer science and the *term yielding a thread* is what I did not understand.

essentially:  `yield()` basically means that the thread is not doing anything that important and if other threads  need to be run, they can run. (I'd prefer to use join as Alex Yu mentioned). Basically, if we want to visualize what `yield` is doing...  whatever thread you call yield on will get pushed to the back of the messaging queue, then other threads with the same priority get executed ahead of it. So it's like going to the back of the line at a club.

Answer (score 22):

I would answer the question in the context of 4 related things:

- Sequence [`yield(value: T)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence-scope/yield.html) is totally unrelated to coroutine [`yield()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html)
- [`isActive`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/is-active.html) is just a flag to identify if the coroutine is still active or cancelled. You can check this flag periodically and decide to stop current coroutine or continue. Of course, normally, we only continue if it's `true`. Otherwise don't run anything or throws exception, ex. `CancellationException`.
- [`ensureActive()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/ensure-active.html) checks the `isActive` flag above and throws `CancellationException` if it's `false`.
- Coroutine [`yield()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) not only [calls `ensureActive()` first](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/0d26d6c389ab29661383591f6e3c3f21caceb402/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Yield.kt#L33), but then also politely tells other coroutines in the same dispatcher that: "Hey, you guys could go first, then I will continue." The reason could be "My job is not so important at the moment." or "I am sorry to block you guys for so long. I am not a selfish person, so it's your turn now." You can understand here exactly like this meaning in [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/yield_2): "yield (to somebody/something): to allow vehicles on a bigger road to go first." SYNONYM: give way.

Answer (score 17):

@Vasile's answer is the most relevant to the question, the accepted answer from @Yuri Schimke is just general information that doesn't actually answer the question.

To illustrate the need for the first `yield`, let's change the code slightly by adding two "** is running*" statements:

```
val job = launch {
    val child = launch {
        try {
            println("Child is running")
            delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        } finally {
            println("Child is cancelled")
        }
    }
    
    yield() // without this, child job doesn't get executed
    println("Cancelling child")
    child.cancel()
    child.join()
    yield()
    println("Parent is not cancelled")
}
println("Parent is running")
job.join()
```

**Output:**

```
Parent is running
Child is running
Cancelling child
Child is cancelled
Parent is not cancelled
```

Without the first `yield`, "*Child is running*" is never printed since the child job doesn't get a chance to run. `delay` suspends child execution and resumes parent execution. `cancel` interrupts the `delay` and moves the execution into the `finally` block. The `join` and the second `yield` have no real effect, but by calling `join` on the child job, we made absolutely sure that any following code is only executed once the child is completed/cancelled.

Comment: That seems a bit harsh.  Question is in this code "I'm not exactly sure what is the purpose of the yield function."

With both canonical doc link and "It temporarily deprioritises the current long running CPU task, giving other tasks a fair opportunity to run."

Comment: @abhijit this is a great example thanks. but the accepted answer is re-stating what you wrote already formally.

Comment: @j2emanue "_the accepted answer is re-stating what you wrote_": I don't think so, else I'd not have the taken the time. But we can agree to disagree, it's not a competition.

Answer (score 8):

I'm also new to coroutines and my understanding of the coroutine flow is that the code inside the `launch` will execute like the last execution, right before exiting main function. To put some priorities we use - `delay, yield, join`. In this example we can change `yield` with `delay` and will be the same result.

The flow:

1. application jump over `job = launch` get to `job.join()` and
   understand that the future code is waiting that job = launch' will
   finish
2. application jump over `child= launch` get to `yield()` or
   we can use `delay(10)` and understand that future code is not
   important and is going back to the beginning so to `child= launch`
3. get to `delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)` it's a trap
4. application get to `println("Cancelling child")` then to `child.cancel()` and `child.join()` who is a flow trigger. In this case we can substitute it with `yield or join` . After this trigger application understand that `child = launch` is canceled but `finally` statement is not executed and execute it `println("Child is cancelled")` .
5. Execute `yield()`(i find it useless) then `println("Parent is not cancelled")` .

   Your Question ---  yield() //why do i need this ???????
   Because without `yield` the app will not get back to `child= launch` will not get inside `try` block and after when the code will get to child.join(), `finally`  with `println("Child is cancelled")` will not be executed because `try` block was not triggered before.

I advice to run this code in debug mode and put breakpoints on every line and use "F9" in Intellij to understand the flow, and also experiment with  Alex Yu code from playground and change `delay, yield, join`

Answer (score 7):

In your example, yield() is called inside parent job. It says to your parent: "you work much more, wait please, i will let the other tasks to work for some time, after some time i will let you continue to work ".

Thus parent job waits..
Child job works some time..
After some time, parent job passes the next line which comes after yield(), and cancels the child job.

If you do not use yield() in your example, parent job immediately cancels child job.

Let me explain the yield with different example which shows yield in much more clear way. 2 jobs wait in the queue for waiting thread to let them to work. When you call yield, thread looks into the queue and sees other job waiting so it lets the other job to work.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.yield

fun main() = runBlocking {


    val job1 = launch {
        repeat(10) {
            delay(1000)
            println("$it. step done in job 1 ")
            yield()
        }
    }

    val job2 = launch {
        repeat(10) {
            delay(1000)
            println("$it. step done in job 2 ")
            yield()
        }
    }

    job1.join()
    job2.join()
    println("done")
}
```

Output:

```
0. step done in job 1 
0. step done in job 2 
1. step done in job 1 
1. step done in job 2 
2. step done in job 1 
2. step done in job 2 
3. step done in job 1 
3. step done in job 2 
4. step done in job 1 
4. step done in job 2 
5. step done in job 1 
5. step done in job 2 
6. step done in job 1 
6. step done in job 2 
7. step done in job 1 
7. step done in job 2 
8. step done in job 1 
8. step done in job 2 
9. step done in job 1 
9. step done in job 2 
done
```

Comment: its working exactly the same without yield as well

Comment: @jknair That's because this is just an illustration: `delay` doesn't spend CPU time (and in fact will itself `yield`). If you were doing something like cryptography (or even using `Thread.sleep`), you'd see a difference.

Comment: `delay` should be removed from the code (because it effectively works like `yield` while delaying)

Answer (score 2):

Read below comments in code for description:

```
runBlocking {

        // Main job thread in example
        val job = launch {

            // Child job thread
            val child = launch {
                try {
                    println("logTag: Child before delay")
                    delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
                    println("logTag: Child after delay")
                } finally {
                    println("logTag: Child is cancelled")
                }
            }

            // If you remove this yield, above child job thread will never execute.
            // And before execution, child job will be cancelled via below line child.cancel().
            // Here yield() is saying that thread (main job thread) is not doing anything that important and if other threads (i.e. child job thread) need to be run, they can run.
            // Try yourself, after commenting/uncommenting this yield(), and observe response.
            yield()

            println("logTag: Cancelling... child")
            child.cancel()
            child.join()

            // This is permitting other thread need to be run, if available.
            // This yield() doing nothing because there is no more active threads available. Because child job thread already cancelled above.
            // After commenting/uncommenting this, no change in response.
            yield()

            println("logTag: Parent is not cancelled")
        }
        job.join()
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
suspend fun yield(): Unit (source)
```

[Yields](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) the thread (or thread pool) of the current `coroutine` dispatcher to other `coroutine` to run if possible.

This suspending function is cancellable. If the Job of the current `coroutine`  is canceled or completed when this suspending function is invoked or while this function is waiting for dispatch, it resumes with a `CancellationException`.

**Note:** *This function always checks for cancellation even when it does not suspend.*

Comment: the coroutine `yield` has nothing to do with the sequence `yield`.