# How to launch lifecycle.whenResumed coroutine immediately so flow-collection starts before returning?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I listen to a flow in whenResumed, so events are only collected while app is resumed. However I would like to ensure that I have started listeners before I run code that might send events that must be collected.

```
init {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        stateUpdates.collect { onUpdate(it) }
    }
    // Now do stuff that might trigger event, which I want to collect above.
    // This does not have to be in init {}, an initialize() is fine
    doMyThing()
}
```

I know I can use a sharedFlow with a cache, but for my usage-case, a cache might be problematic.

--

I know I can do the following, where line 1 is executed immediately, but here again line 2 is dispatched and thus executed later:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
    // 1
    lifecycle.whenResumed {
        // 2
    }
}
```

==== Update 3. March 2022

Thanks IR42 for good info on option. What I was actually after is scheduling many different types of collectors, and then do my thing.

```
init {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        launch { stateUpdates1.collect { onUpdate1(it) } }
        launch { stateUpdates2.collect { onUpdate2(it) } }
        launch { stateUpdates3.collect { onUpdate3(it) } }
        launch { stateUpdates4.collect { onUpdate4(it) } }
        launch { stateUpdates5.collect { onUpdate5(it) } }
    }
    // Now do stuff that might trigger event, which I want to collect above.
    // This does not have to be in init {}, an initialize() is fine
    doMyThing()
}
```

I would like a nice idiomatic way of doing this. I don't see how to do that with onSubscription(), though I appreciate the input as it was new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. It requires yielding inside a coroutine, so other all other coroutines scheduled on the same Dispatcher (such as Main thread) has chance to run.

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    launch { stateUpdates1.collect { onUpdate1(it) } }
    launch { stateUpdates2.collect { onUpdate2(it) } }
}
// do other stuff if needed here, or join the two coroutines
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    yield()
    // Do my thing, that might result in state-update
    doMyThing()
}
```

The above would work just as well if `yield() + doMyThing()` was inside same coroutine.

See [Kotlin Coroutine Yield](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html)
and this other question [What is the purpose of coroutine yield()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967529/what-is-the-purpose-of-coroutine-yield)

Note I had a previous bad answer involving runBlocking { }. RunBlocking blocks my UI-thread which is bad design, even if the code executes immediately. It also does not execute other scheduled coroutines while inside runBlocking, which was not what I expected. I deleted that from the answer, because it shouldn't be used in production code. See also [Kotlin coroutines `runBlocking`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331373/kotlin-coroutines-runblocking)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onSubscription](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-subscription.html)

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    stateUpdates
        .onSubscription { 
            // Do my thing, that might result in state-update 
        }
        .collect { onUpdate(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
runBlocking {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        stateUpdates.collect { onUpdate(it) }
    }
    yield()
}
```

Do this, which is less fragile:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    yield()
    stateUpdates.collect { onUpdate(it) }
}
```

It's still a bit fragile, though, because it relies on the order coroutines were submitted.

Comment: In your suggestion I cannot see there `doMyThing()` is. The collector never returns. Yielding like this will not have the desired effect, as what I want is to run the line `.collect` before `doMyThing()`. Yield() here will let all other current tasks run, but since there are none, nothing happens. runBlocking example will work, as that is what yield does, it waits for execution of all other currently scheduled tasks, but it won't work if the launchWhenResumed was out-side runBlocking, and we don't wan't to block UI-thread. I'll edit my answer, as I should point this out

Comment: I'll admit I didn't look closely at your question before. I was just pointing out a problem with the solution you posted before. Really, it seems like you have an XY problem. You should try to design it so your code doesn't have to care when the collectors are running or not. After all, they are going to be launched, canceled, and restarted multiple times, so why does it matter that they happen to be currently running at the time this `doMyThing()` is called? That is very fragile, and will be very hard to guarantee happens.

Comment: np, and thank you for the time. Its an event driven GUI, and if the event-listeners are slow to attach, they may lose an initial signal. There are GUI components that listen to what is in the GUI-models, and respond accordingly. I need those listeners to be attached before I proceed, and that seems pretty standard. Often I have seen android code that does handler.post() just to get behind the stack, but that's pretty ugly and fragile. It seems like a very basic requirement to me, though it is true that maybe I shouldn't be so cautious of using cacheLast. It would work with current code.

Comment: StateFlow and SharedFlow with a replay will guarantee that an initial signal is replayed whenever the listeners are attached.

Comment: Yeah, they will always replay the last signal, but I'm not sure that fits my use-case so well.