# How properly cancel or close within `try-finally`/`synchronized()`/`Closesable.use { }` in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I really have to say that I love coroutines in Kotlin but I honestly do not understand the behaviour of corotuine cancellation in constructions like

```
coroutineScope {
- try-(catch-)finally { }
- (Closeable { -> ... }).use { }
- synchronized(gate) { }
}
```

### `try-finally`

Let's take a closer look at an example for `try-finally`

```kotlin
@Test
fun `finally gets partially called`() {
    var notReachedEndOfTry = true
    var reachedBeginningOfFinally = false
    var notReachedEndOfFinally = true
    var reachedOuterFinally = false
    val awaiter = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()

    runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val job = launch {
                try {
                    try {
                        awaiter.complete(Unit)
                        // During delay the delay gets cancelled
                        delay(1.seconds)
                        // Not called:
                        notReachedEndOfTry = false
                    } finally {
                        // Called! Why?!?!?!?
                        reachedBeginningOfFinally = true
                        // Suspends again and never returns
                        delay(1.seconds)
                        // Not called:
                        notReachedEndOfFinally = false
                    }
                } finally {
                    // This gets called!??!!??
                    reachedOuterFinally = true
                }
            }

            launch {
                awaiter.await()
                delay(500.milliseconds)
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    assert(notReachedEndOfTry)
    assert(reachedBeginningOfFinally)
    assert(notReachedEndOfFinally)
    assert(reachedOuterFinally)
}
```

I didn't expect the outer finally being called, so why the outer finally gets called after the inner finally got "cancelled" after `yield()`? Is it a compiler-trick to transform try-finally into this behaviour? Is it always ensured that finally gets called? Can you find some documentation regarding this?

### `Closeable.use {}`

Let's take another example for Closeable

```kotlin
@Test
fun `resource will not be closed`() {
    var reachedBeginningOfUse = false
    var notClosed = true
    val closeable = Closeable { notClosed = false }
    val awaiter = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()

    runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val job = launch {
                closeable.use {
                    reachedBeginningOfUse = true
                    awaiter.complete(Unit)
                    delay(1.seconds)
                }
            }

            launch {
                awaiter.await()
                delay(500.milliseconds)
                job.cancel()
            }

            assert(reachedBeginningOfUse)
            assert(notClosed)
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>Here the resource won't be closed!</strike> I know you can use `suspendCancellableCoroutine { invokeOnCancellation { ... }  }` but is it the right approach?

EDIT: Resource will be closed. The asserts should not be in the runBlocking-block. *facepalm*

### `synchronized() {}`

For `synchronized(gate) {}` I am already aware of ReentrantLock in combination with condition, Mutex and Semaphore.

I hope you can answer one or the other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of coroutine yield()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967529/what-is-the-purpose-of-coroutine-yield)

Comment: Did you read the question? `yield()` is just a suspend function that suspends immediatelly to demonstrate the behaviour. Can be anything for example `delay(1.seconds)`.

Comment: There are multiple questions vaguely mixed up here, so, I’ve no idea which one question you’re referring to in your comment.

Comment: I see. You can understand the questions by reading the code with comments. I will add some explanation, I hope this makes things more clear. Thanks

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I was referring to the SO question. This term is overall spread over for example in the link (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/[id]/[description]`) or the button labled "Ask Question" or in the left bar the button "Questions". :P

Comment: Why wouldn't `finally` get called in the first case? The whole point of `finally` is the guarantee that it will always be called no matter what. Or are you just wondering how they implemented it in a way that works with the JVM? The thing I'm confused about is `use` not closing the resource since it's an inline function that uses `finally` so it should behave the same as the first case. But my CompletableDeferred use is rudimentary so I'm not sure if the test is correct. Your assertions are kind of making my head spin from all the double negatives (not/false in the assertion).

Comment: @Tenfour04 Regarding double negatives: updated! I also wondered, why finally wasn't called in Closeable.use and yes, that was my intention, to understand how try-finally is transformed to support suspension points (is it?), so I can understand why the finally is getting called in first place when cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, cancelling a coroutine just throws an exception, `CancellationException`. That should explain all the behaviour you are seeing: Every `finally` block gets called as you would expect with any other exception, but if you call another `suspend` function inside the `finally`, that again throws `CancellationException` so the rest of the `finally` block is skipped.

This is why, if you ever `catch (e: Exception)` inside a coroutine, you should always add a catch-and-rethrow for `CancellationException`.

Comment: Omg... Now I get it. The finally is really just hit because the exception will be "returned" from the coroutine "manager" (the one who iterates through all the suspending points, forwarding to the dispatcher etc.) to the coroutine back, so finally gets notified. By the way, your last statement I do not get fully. Since I do not use catch here, it automatically rethrows/passes through the exceptions, but you just wanted to point that out in general, right?

Comment: Technically it's thrown, not returned. But yes. And you're right about the general point, if you have no `catch` at all you're fine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 pointed me to the fact that Closeable.use just implements try-finally. Do you know why the implementation of `close` is not called in the internally finally-block implementation of Closeable.use?

Comment: @Teneko It might have something to do with that code starting with `closed=true` in the first place. Something about double negatives? In other words, I think that close method *is* called but you're not seeing it.

Comment: I think I found the answer: because the Closeable.use is no suspendable function, the coroutine "manager" cannot "return" once an excpetion has been thrown. By the way I use "" to emphise it returns to the coroutine scope but of course it will "return and throw".

Comment: Haha double negatives. I updated the code, sorry haha - was not my intention to confuse you.

Comment: You were right! :D I accidentally had the asserts in runBlocking and were faster (obviously) evaluated than the code in launch-blocks.